# tkinter all widgets ontop of eachother

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm working on a project that is a GUI (first time using tkinter). I couldn't find anything related to my issue, every widget is like stuck together on top of one another.

I've tried changing the `padx`, `pady`, `rows`, `column`, and some other stuff.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
vpn = tk.Tk()
#vpn.option_add("*Button.Background", "white")
#vpn.option_add("*Button.Foreground", "black")
vpn.title('testing')
vpn.geometry("630x360")
vpn.resizable(0, 0)
#main = tk.Frame(master=vpn,bg='grey')
#main.pack_propagate(0)
#main.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
variable = StringVar(vpn)
variable.set("Locations")
servers = OptionMenu(vpn, variable, "US", "CA", "RU", "UK", 'CH')
servers.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=195, pady=325)
close = tk.Button(vpn, text='Connect')
close.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=230, pady=325)

support = tk.Button(vpn, text='Help')
support.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=450, pady=325)
vpn.mainloop()
```

[image: img]

Comment: You put `row=0, column=0` on all the widgets. Isn't it natural for them to stack on top of each other?

Comment: this is my first time using tkinter, how should i do it then?

Answer (score 0):

As Henry Yik said you have placed all your widgets in the same spot at `row=0, column=0`

All you need to do is set different values for each widget's row/column value, e.g.:

```
servers.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=195, pady=325)
close.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=230, pady=325)
support.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=450, pady=325)
```

`padx` and `pady` is used for creating empty space ("air padding") around widgets so that they don't touch each other when placed.

There are 3 different ways to place widgets in tkinter: `grid` (this is what you used), `pack` and `place`. [Read this](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_layout_management.php) for information on how to use them.